# Mongoose: Find name similar to input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an auto complete input box that I am working on and I am trying to make a mongoose endpoint that will get me user objects based on data from the input. The data can be incomplete, but it should still get everything that is similar. eg:

```
var input = "st";

// Should return a user object like this one.

var userObject = {
  name: {
    full: 'Stephen Brinkworth',
    first: 'Stephen',
    last: 'Brinkworth'
  }
};
```

I have looked into the issue and from what I have seen, the recommended endpoint looks like this.

```
User.find({name: {full: new RegExp(req.query.input, 'i')}}).exec(...);
```

The only problem I have is that when I use this endpoint, I consistently get back an empty array. Can anyone help me with this? Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to employ the use of MongoDB's [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator:

> Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries.

The `$regex` operator can be utilized using one of the following syntax as specified in the documentation:

> ```
> { <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
> ```

```
{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }  
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/<options> } }
```

A simple solution using the `$regex` operator would be:

```
var nameRegex = new RegExp(req.query.input);
User.find({'name.full': {$regex: nameRegex, $options: 'i'}});
```

Comment: that worked thanks :) I just needed to use the 'name.full' and it made both ways work correctly.

Comment: Thanks alot, this works but I had to change "options" to "$options", just add the dollar sign